# How can we achieve deep linking in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, deep-linking, angular2-routing

Deep linking : encoding the current state of application in the URL so that it can be bookmarked.
Am not able to bookmark any of my routes in *Angular2* ! how can this be achieved ?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) on the new router built into Angular 2? Is there a particular aspect of the routing that is not working in your case? What have you tried?

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If your routes work what happens when you reload page on a specific route? Your problem description is seriously lacking in proper level of detail.

Comment: Please provide more information. What do your URL look like? What does your route config look like?